# How to convert "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" to "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss" in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I used the lubridate package to convert out of an odd format, but now an stuck with yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (the default r datetime format), when I need the data to be in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss. I have been unable to find anything that converts out of the default r datetime format, only things that convert to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need `format`

```
format(Sys.time(), "%m/%d/%Y %T")
```

Or more explicitly

```
format(Sys.time(), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```